# WebStorm и ESLint

Tags: config, webstorm, eslint

В учебном проекте после установки пакетов:eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier prettier lint-staged husky --save-dev, для настройки редактора 
Visual Studio Code в файл с настройками добавляют следующие строки:

```css
"editor.formatOnPaste": false,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},
"[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
},
"[json]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
},
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
"eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
```

Вопрос:Нужно ли что-то подобное делать для редактора WebStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. Для того чтобы форматировать код в WebStorm с помощью ESLint+prettier, нужно [настроить ESLint интеграцию](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_activate) и использовать ESLint quick fixes, доступные по `Alt+Enter`.

Если хочется запускать `eslint --fix` при сохранении, нужно настроить [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/using-file-watchers.html#). Опцию **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** рекомендуется выключить, чтобы форматирование происходило только по `Ctrl+S`, а не в процессе редактирования